# Self contains Self property

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-runtime

I was messing around with Objective-C and I stumbled upon something strange. The following code compiles and works the way I want it to.

```
self.scrollView.delegate = self.self.self.self.self;
// equivalent to         = self;
```

Why does this compile? Is it the case that `self` is a property of an object. If so, I have never seen `self` declared as a property. I thought `self` referred to the instance of the class you are creating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me turn this around Why shoudn't it compile nor work as expected?

`self` is a property of `NSObject`. It always points to the object itself. Every object inheriting from `NSObject` has it.

As you say, `self` refers to the instance. Well, it is not only valid in the context of creating instances. It is always there. And it is very helpful.

`[self myProperty]` or `self.myProperty` refers explicitely (*laugh* more or less explicitely but it does) to the getter (or the setter) of the property `myProperty` while just typing myProperty within a method refers directly to the property without passing the getter.

Another example is `someOjbect.delegate = self;` or so.

So, as `self` alsways refers to an object, to the very object, it has a `self` property that refers to the very object which has a `self` property ...

BTW, classes are objects in Objective-C that inherit from Class. In the context of a class, i.e. in class methods, it refers to the class object of the very class. You can play the same game there. If you start off with an instance, then you can play the game with the class property.

```
self.class.class.class == [self class].self.class.self
```

should evaluate to YES. (Well, I never tried that myself. If you actually try it and find this wrong, then please let me know)

Comment: `Class` is not a class, it's a type of pointer, like `id`. Classes in Cocoa inherit from `NSObject`'s metaclass.

Comment: @Hermann thankyou for clarifying that `self` is a property.

Comment: @JoshCaswell A minor nitpick: Classes in Objective-C inherit from their base class' metaclass.  That's usually NSObject's but it could be NSProxy's...or something else.

Comment: @JoshCaswell, classes are objects. You are right. `id` is a pointer to an object. Objects have types and types of objects are classes. They are different though. `Class` objects are sort of singletons. They are not really instanciated but initialized (with initialize, not init) when an object of the class is instanciated for the first time. See http://examples.oreilly.com/9780596809775/ObjC.pdf page 28ff for details. In the end, `id` may even point to a class object, but cannot point to everything. As stated in the linked pdf, `id myClass = self.class;` is a valid and meaningful statment.

Comment: @HermannKlecker: My comment was directed at your statement "classes are objects in Objective-C that inherit from Class." Nothing can inherit from `Class`, because it's not a class.

Comment: @NateChandler, you're absolutely right. Thanks for picking a nit on my nitpick!

Comment: @NateChandler, ah, yes, you are right with that.

Answer (score 1):

`self` is a method in the [`NSObject` *protocol*](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/self). It returns the object it is called on, it is rather pointless.

This is distinct from the *local variable* `self`, which within a method refers to the object the method was called on.

Both the method and the local variable apply to class objects as well as standard instances, so a class method has a `self` local variable and a class object a `self` method.